# Cannot update ubuntu15.04

Tags: server

My internet connection works fine but I continually get message  "download failed, check your internet connection" I've changed servers with no change in results. I'm connected to router with ethernet cable and received the download failure message on 3 separate days with ping check at 50 or close.  Today the download went thru fine after checking ping at 47. Current problem solved but still puzzled why it went ok with a slightly lower ping and with identical configuration. I'm a newby and don't know how to bring up the error log, by the way.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the complete relevant part of the errorlog, please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a wired connection to access the internet or using Wi-Fi? Just because your internet connection seems to "work fine" doesn't mean it does.

You might be losing some package which could result in the error you are getting. If you are using Wi-Fi, try again with an ethernet cable. If you're already using a cable, an easy way to determine if you are losing package is to run a ping command and leave it running for a while.

```
ping google.com
```

After running this command for a while you'll know if you are losing package. Might be a problem with your internet connection. There isn't enough detail in your questions to help you. Can you post the compete error message?

itSp4x

Comment: forgot to mention if you want to stop a ping command in the terminal press "ctrl+z"